# Hide CSS and HTML from ie6 users?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

I'm trying to force my ie6 users to upgrade to modern browsers when viewing my site. Since it's too time consuming to modify everything to work for ie6. Since everything looks broken I'd rather just hide the whole CSS + HTML and only display a pop up browser. My question is, how do I set all elements to not display if a user is using ie6?

Thanks

Comment: Isn't the fact that everything is badly displayed enough ? In any case, a simple alert would be offensive enough in my opinion...

Comment: Good luck reasoning with IE6 users.

Comment: Somebody who's still on IE6 has probably a good reason, like an oath, or a very old computer. He deserves more compassion than injuries.

Comment: you could wrap the entire <body/> content in a conditional comment. <!--[if gt IE 6)]><!-->  your html <!--<![endif]-->

Comment: @dysroy you mean leave the page looking like it was hacked and sliced?  Isn't it better to display an empty page and ask user to upgrade then offer them choice of using a 70% broken website

Comment: Unfortunately it's the case that many users aren't using it by choice and it's their company relying on outdated services that push it, so maybe don't just disable your site entirely, and don't be offensive, remember most people don't know what a browser is

Comment: @JanDvorak Inrbo is right it is a difference between `<!--[if gt IE 6)]><!-->` and `<!--[if gt IE 6)]>`  with the `<!-->` it is for IE greater 6 and all other browsers

Comment: I think I should have rephrased my question. A lot of my users are gonna be Chinese and the main reason some are still using ie6 is because they're on pirated XP machines and don't usually look at tech sites to know FF, chrome and opera can be installed without having their machine busted for piracy. So I need to get them to update, be able to view my site and still not compromise their machine

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<!--[if IE 6]>
    Special instructions for IE 6 here
<![endif]-->
```

Example:

```
<!--[if IE 6]>
    <style type="text/css">
         #browserWarning { display:block; }
         /* hide content here */
     </style>
<![endif]-->
```

http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html

Comment: Why not `<!--[if lte IE 6]>`? You never know when you'll get an IE 5.5 visitor.

Answer (score 0):

You could add this at the top of your pages in the head element to redirect the user to specific page.

```
if (navigator.userAgent.match(/MSIE/i)) {
    document.location.replace("/ie6warning.html");
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I'm trying to do now. However all of the above methods still loads the page first and then redirects. I would like to be able to redirect or hide the page before _any_ of the page contents are loaded

Comment: If you don't want it to hit the page at all then you should using a rewriting rule in your webserver. For instance for apache it would be something like:
RewriteEngine  on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT}  ^MSIE 6.0